# Android Service issue

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create my first android service and am having some issues. I have looked all over and do not know what I am doing wrong. My goal is to create a service that maxes out my volume when the speaker phone is turned on.

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Matthew
 * Date: 12/17/10
 * Time: 9:36 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();//timer constructor
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
        startService();
    }

    public void startService()
    {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
         {
              AudioManager am;
              public boolean speakerPhone = false;
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
              //I am not sure what should go here...
              //I want the volume to go to max volume when I turn the speaker phone on

                   /*
                   //if(am.isSpeakerphoneOn())
                   {
                        am.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,                   
                              AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 2);
                   }
                   */
              }
         },0,1000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService();
    }
    public void stopService()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(timer != null)
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong? Are you getting an error or is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to provide more information.  For example, output and such.  Did it compile?   When you run it, does the service show up in the process list?

Second, break it up.  Make a service that launches hello world.  Make an application that changes the volume.  Writing lots of little Android test cases is the best way to explore the API.

Third, that override to IBinder looks extremely odd.  Take the time to walk through the API Demo code for the Alarm app, specifically apis/app/AlarmService_Service.java.

Keep at it.

Charles